# Grails 2.2.1 Mails Config Change on user interaction

Tags: email

I have Grails 2.2.1 application. I need to allow user to select their own mail server and send mail. I tried different methods mentioned in other post but none helped. I could change mail config but while sending mail always used old one. 
I also tried below code after changing:
  pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin("mail").notifyOfEvent(GrailsPlugin.EVENT_ON_CONFIG_CHANGE, grailsApplication.config)

to notify config change. But result was same.

Please if anyone could help resolve this issue.